# How to forward emails with perl's Net::IMAP::Simple

Tags: perl, email, imap

There seem to be hundreds of questions in a similar vein. I think have read them all but none seem to answer this question. I have looked at FetchMail but don't think I can install it on my DreamHost shared server. I have looked at Mail::Box, but cannot figure out how to log in and collect the mail I want to forward.
I am currently trying to do it as shown below ... obviously this has been simplified to make it easier to follow and may contain errors. But essentially I am taking the body of the read mail and trying to post that on as the body of the forwarded email.

The mail is read and forwarded correctly but when viewing the forwarded mail all the formatting is wrong and sometimes it is truncated.

```
use Net::IMAP::Simple;
use Email::Simple;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use Email::Address;

# Connect
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple->new($Server, port  => 993,  use_ssl => 1,) || die "Unable to connect to IMAP: $Net::IMAP::Simple::errstr\n";

# Log in
if ( !$imap->login( $L, $P ) ) {print  "Login failed for $L: " . $imap->errstr . "\n"; exit(64);}

# Look in the inbox
my $nm = $imap->select('Inbox');

## Iterate through all messages
for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= $nm ; $i++ ) {
my $es = Email::Simple->new( join '', @{ $imap->get($i) } );
$Body = $es->body;

use Net::SMTP::SSL;
my $smtp;
if (not $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new($Server, Port => 465, Debug => 0)) {warn "Could not connect to $Server!\n"; $method = 'Server Fail'; $error=$@;} else {

if (not $smtp->auth($L2, $P2)) {warn "Authentication Failed! Login: $L sending from $from TO $to\n"; $method = "Authentication Fail Login: $L2 $P2 sending from $from TO $to\n"; $error=$@;} else {

$smtp->mail($from . "\n");
$smtp->to($to . "\n");
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
$smtp->datasend("From: " . $from . "\n");
$smtp->datasend("To: " . $to . "\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: " . $subject . "\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend($Body . "\n");
$smtp->dataend();
# Check it was sent correctly 
$result = $smtp->message();
if ($result !~ /OK/i) {$error = $result; if ($result =~ /quota exceeded/) {$method = 'Quota Blocking'; } else {$method = 'Bad Address';}}

$smtp->quit;

# Copy this message
$imap->create_mailbox( "Inbox.Processed" );
$imap->copy( $i, "Inbox.Processed" ) or die $imap->errstr;
$imap->delete( $i );
```

Comment: From what I can see, `Mail::Box` has an extensive [support for forwarding](https://metacpan.org/dist/Mail-Message/view/lib/Mail/Message.pod#Constructing-a-message) (what I don't see in other libs).  It is a bit complex with a hierarchy of classes but perhaps it is ultimately simpler to learn how to use it then to try to rig your own (which may not work out).  Was it so hard to get it going?  There are resources, even a [cookbook](https://perl.mines-albi.fr/perl5.6.1/site_perl/5.6.1/Mail/Box-Cookbook.html) of sorts and an [author's website](http://perl.overmeer.net/mailbox/) for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I cannot work out how to log in and retrieve the emails. I think it must assume that I am running my own email server. Whereas I am on a Dreamhost shared server using their mailboxes. Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Yeah, that's mentioned in the question ... I see two ways: (1) the library has a component supposedly for that, `Mail::Box::IMAP4` (2) Retrieve messages in another way (like you do now?), and then use this library to manipulate (forward) them.  Perhaps dump all messages into a "folder" for `Mail::Box`. That's a sort of an extra pass but it may be simpler than the alternatives -- essentially to figure out how to implement forwarding so it seems. (Btw, I have no idea what "_Dreamhost shared server_" is or implies, or whether it somehow invalidates what I'm thinking...)

Comment: There are "hundreds of questions in a similar vein" and you have "read them all but none seem to answer", and then your actual question is how to log in to the server?

Comment: No, sorry if I confused you. My question is: how to forward email using Net::IMAP::Simple.

Comment: @arnt  Logging into server problem was about `Mail::Box`.  Melchester -- you get to your messages in three lines of code -- can you then drop the mailbox to disk and then use `Mail::Box` to forward from it? I keep coming back to this because it has a ready functionality while otherwise it seems like you'd have to do a lot of tricky work.

Comment: Yes Mail::Box does look very capable - and the developer was very helpful - but I think the application is beyond my skill level. I just couldn't figure out how to use it to do what I wanted.

Comment: @Melchester Alright then -- I was considering to write an asnwer but I see that you got it, and the way you wanted it! Good job :)

Answer (score 2):

This is all you have to do. Simply have two "sessions" of `Net::Imap::Simple` running and copy the message from one to the other.

```
    use Net::IMAP::Simple;
    use IO::Socket::SSL;
    # Conntect to the TO mailbox       
    $imap2 = Net::IMAP::Simple->new('smtp.SomeServer.com', port  => 993,  use_ssl => 1,) || die "Unable to connect to IMAP: $Net::IMAP::Simple::errstr\n";
    $L2 = 'TOaddress@mail.com';
    $P2 = 'password';
    # Log in
    if ( !$imap2->login( $L2, $P2 ) ) {print  "Login failed for $L2: " . $imap2->errstr . "\n"; exit(64);}
    
    # Connect to the From Mail box
    $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple->new('smtp.SomeOtherServer.com', port  => 993,  use_ssl => 1,) || die "Unable to connect to IMAP: $Net::IMAP::Simple::errstr\n";
     $L = 'FROMaddress@mail.com';
    $P = 'password';   
    # Log in
    if ( !$imap->login( $L, $P ) ) {print  "Login failed for $L: " . $imap->errstr . "\n"; exit(64);}
    
    # Look in the inbox
    my $nm = $imap->select('Inbox');
    
    ## Iterate through all messages
    for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= $nm ; $i++ ) {
    $message = $imap->get( $i ) or die $imap->errstr;
    @flags = $imap->msg_flags($i);
    
    # Move this message into a processed folder
    $imap->create_mailbox( "Inbox.Processed" );
    $imap->copy( $i, "Inbox.Processed" ) or die $imap->errstr;
    $imap->delete( $i );
    
    # Copy to other mail address ...
    $imap2->put( 'Inbox', $message, @flags ) or die $imap2->errstr;
    
    }
    
    # Disconnect
    $imap->quit;
    $imap2->quit;
```